# Dagger2 singleton in Kotlin and Java

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, dagger-2

I would like to inject to a class as singleton, but Dagger injects other instance to Kotlin file than to Java files.
Why does it happen?

Comment: You probably forgot `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the code, so it's not easy to give a full answer. However, my guess is that you're creating 2 different instances of your component, one in Kotlin and one in Java.
Dagger, however, can "guarantee" the single instance only when you reuse always the same component. If you create two different instances of your component, one in Kotlin and one in Java, it won't be able to reuse the same instance of your "singleton" module.

The reason behind this, is that when generating the components, Dagger inserts some logic to create a new instance of your module the first time you call it, then it returns the "cached" instance all subsequent times you want to get the same module.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, but which part of my code should I show.
I have been using this class as singleton (by Dagger) for a very long time.
Now I just added my activity written in Kotlin to my appComponent class, and in the activity's onCreate() I get the appComponent from Application as in my other classes (written in Java) and I tried to inject my singleton with @Inject annotation, but the class is injected into kt file is not the same that is injected into other java files.

Comment: could you please show how you get your component from Kotlin?

Comment: (application as IndexApplication).appComponent.inject(this)
I init application like a singleton in my Application class
https://pastebin.com/Lqwx83Bn